# Video wont upload to specific directory? [PHP]

Tags: php, file-upload

Right now i have a video from my Android phone upload to **/var/www/html/ProductVideos** but i want to create a new directory and store the video there. The directory is created but it isn't in 777 permissions and the video is uploaded fine.

(i get the video from my Android phone and then send it to the server)

Before PHP:
[image]

After PHP:
[image]

My questions:

> Why isn't the new directory being created with 777 permissions?
>
> Why isn't my video being uploaded to my new directory?

My assumptions: I think because for some reason my directory isn't being created with the 777 permissions the video defaults to the **/var/www/html/ProductVideos** and maybe because i am sending the video as a multipart?

PHP code:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['myFile']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['myFile']['type'];
$temp_name = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];

$ProductAccountName = $_POST['ProductAccountName'];

$NewDirectory = "/var/www/html/ProductVideos/" . $ProductAccountName;
if (!file_exists($NewDirectory))
    {
        mkdir($NewDirectory, 0777, true);
    }

//$location = "/var/www/html/ProductVideos/".$ProductAccountName;//."/";

move_uploaded_file($temp_name, '/var/www/html/ProductVideos/' .    $ProductAccountName . '/' . $file_name);

echo   "Uploaded!";
}else{
echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
$file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['myFile']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['myFile']['type'];
$temp_name = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];

$ProductAccountName = $_POST['ProductAccountName'];

$NewDirectory = "ProductVideos/" . $ProductAccountName;

if(!is_dir($NewDirectory))
{
    mkdir($NewDirectory, 0777, true);
}

move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $NewDirectory.'/' . $file_name);

echo   "Uploaded!";
}else{
echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Comment: yea you only changed the 2 lines and thats what i updated